# HTML/CSS to png

Tags: html, css, png, jpeg

I'm new to coding/devlopment, and after doing some html and css pages, I realized that I can use html and css to make designs just like photoshop but with code. For example: A div with a height, a width, and a color outline to make a box with an outline.

What I'm trying to do here is save the content of a page (html AND css) in a png or jpeg file to have it the right size and put it as a pc wallpaper.

can you please help me?

I am open to talking on discord with French-speaking people since I use a translator to write in English.

All i can ^^', i ive try to save as .png my html file, put my folder which contain my project on a website who can convert my files to png...

Answer (score 0):

Your request is very open-ended, so I'm not sure we can help you. So I'm gonna try to be as helpful as I can.

As far as I understand, you're designing something with html and css, and then want to save that as an image.

I'm not sure why you can't do that with a simple screenshot (assuming you have an application where you can cut the screenshot as you like).

If not try this app which can help you cut any way:
https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html

or get the extension in chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lightshot-screenshot-tool/mbniclmhobmnbdlbpiphghaielnnpgdp?hl=en

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi ! it's because my screen is in 1920x1080, however my page too, so I have the bar to go down on the right side ^^'